# How to show rect of specific cell in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift3

I am using `UICollectionView` in a viewcontroller and passed an array of images. I have enabled paging of collection view . But when i scroll to next image , the previous cell does not disappear completely. It remains at the edge. So, `how I can make only specific image/cell visible while scrolling left/Right.`

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if collectionView == collection_LargeView
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Large Cell", for: indexPath)as! LargeImageCell
        cell.imageView_LargePic.sd_setImage(with:  NSURL(string: array[indexPath.row]) as URL! )
        cellIndex = indexPath
        return cell
    }
    else
    {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Picture Cell", for: indexPath)as! VendorPictureCell
       cell.imageView_VendorPics.sd_setImage(with:  NSURL(string: array[indexPath.row])as URL!)
        return cell
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


     return array.count

}
```

//when item at bottom collection view is selected the other collection view scroll to that indexPath

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if collectionView == collectionView_picturesCollection
    {
      Index = indexPath.row
        collection_LargeView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .right, animated: true)
    }

}
```

**Please solve this.
Thank You.**

[After scrolling from one cell to next Screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/msmnV.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msmnV.jpg)

Comment: give me screen shot of collection view

Comment: Can you please update the code here that you are using?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/msmnV.jpg

Comment: @SahilArora Can you show `sizeForItemAt indexPath` method?

Comment: @Sahil check below answer and if you have any issue with this, let me know. I hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You fist change in your story board's collectionview's in min spacing for cell and for lines to 0 like in below images:

[image]

To

[image]

I hope it may help you

Comment: //Flow Layout Delegate Method
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let cell = collection_LargeView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
        
        return CGSize(width: (cell?.contentView.frame.size.width)!, height: (cell?.contentView.frame.size.height)!)
    }

Answer (score 0):

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

```
  if collectionView == collection_LargeView
  {
    return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 524.0)
    }
  else{
    return CGSize(width: 86.0, height: 74.0)
    }
}
```